# Unable to load XML configuration file from relative path

Tags: java, xml, path, relative-path

My Java program is supposed to load a configuration file from a relative path. First, the configuration file was loaded from a full path and it's worked fine. Now i'm trying to load the configuration file from the relative path, so at the end the configuration file will be loaded from the same path of the exe file.

Here is the code. could anyone tell my what wrong with that? I marked the problematic line with a comment.

Main class:

```
public class App {
    private static Object string;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CsvConfiguration conf = CsvConfiguration.getInstance();
}
```

CsvConfiguration class (relevant parts):

```
public class CsvConfiguration {

    private static CsvConfiguration instance = null;
    private static Document doc = null;

    static{
        URI path;
        try {
            path = Thread.currentThread().getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/csv-generator/src/main/config/config.xml").toURI(); //my program is collapsing in this line
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new File(path));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Config is unparsable");
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    private CsvConfiguration(){
        try{
            setGenerationRate();
            setNumberOfRows();
            setNumberOfColumns();
            setOutputFolder();
        }catch(NumberFormatException nExc){
            throw new RuntimeException(nExc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        setColumnsList();

    }

    public synchronized static CsvConfiguration getInstance(){
        if (instance==null)
            instance = new CsvConfiguration();
        return instance;
    }
```

Comment: Try `new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/path").getPath())`

Comment: All i need is to replace your code with the problematic line? Is URI type can get File type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I've found the problem in the code. It was easier than i expected.

I had to replace the problematic code line with the following code:

```
File configFile = new File("./src/main/config/config.xml");
```